# How can i increase height of iframe when a button is clicked inside the iframe?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, wordpress, iframe

So,i have been working on a wordpress website which has an iframe in a webpage of the website.The iframe contains 2 buttons which uses jquery append to include content in the iframe.Currently i included a javascript function to change the height everytime the iframe is loaded.But i want to change the height when the button inside iframe is pressed.
The iframe is defined inside a plugin file in wordpress and iframe src is defined as a template in wordpress theme folder.
Plugin file containing iframe tag,

```
<iframe src="http://localhost/mysite/firstrate/" frameborder="0" 
scrolling="no" onload="resizeIframe();" id="starwindow" ></iframe>
<script>
var obj=document.getElementById("starwindow");
function resizeIframe() {
obj.style.height = obj.contentWindow.document.body.scrollHeight + 'px';
}
</script>
```

Theme file containing iframe src(template file),

```
<button class="add_form_field" ><span>ADD</span></button>
<button id="button" class="submit_button"> SUBMIT </button>
<input type="radio" class="rating1" id="1star5" name="rating1" value="5" />
<label for="1star5" title="Five Stars">5 stars</label>
<input type="radio" class="rating1" id="1star4" name="rating1" value="4" />
<label for="1star4" title="Four Stars">4 stars</label>
<input type="radio" class="rating1" id="1star3" name="rating1" value="3" />
<label for="1star3" title="Three Stars">3 stars</label>
<input type="radio" class="rating1" id="1star2" name="rating1" value="2" />
<label for="1star2" title="Two Stars">2 stars</label>
<input type="radio" class="rating1" id="1star1" name="rating1" value="1" />
<label for="1star1" title="One Star">1 star</label>
```

[This is the screenshot.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7bleW.png)

I want the iframe to increase the height when buttons are pressed inside the iframe,so no scrollbar appears when buttons are pressed.
Thanking you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that with jQuery:

```
$('#starwindow').load(function(){

        var iframe = $('#starwindow').contents();

        iframe.find("#button").click(function(){
               resizeIframe();
        });
});
```

Change `'#button'` by the element you want to use for the iframe resize.

EDIT:

```
$('#starwindow').load(function(){
    var iframe = $('#starwindow').contents();
    iframe.find("#add").click(function(){
        resizeIframe('add');
    });
    iframe.find("#delete").click(function(){
        resizeIframe('delete');
    });
});
```

and change your function to add / delete height

```
resizeIframe(mode) {
    if(mode=='add') {
        //code to add height
    }
    else {
        //code to delete height
    }
}
```

Comment: I encountered some other problem also.When i press the add button,another button called "delete" is created.How to include that button also in this code,so the iframe height gets decreased.

Comment: I think,i didn't make the problem clear for you.The contents in the iframe changes after Add button is called for the first.A new button Delete is created.(I have now included the screenshot of that in the question).So,  iframe.find("#delete").click(function(){}) will not work because Delete button is not in   var iframe = $('#starwindow').contents().How to include Delete button after Add button is called?

Comment: @codewiz I see, then you have to run var iframe = $('#starwindow').contents(); again to include Delete button

Comment: OK.Thank you for helping.